# How to display fileRead result in an input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I'm using `phonegap` and using it's `fileRead` method to read a txt file.
I can output the contents in the text file by using:

```
function fileRead(evt) {
    alert(evt.target.result);
}
```

but this only gives me an alert of the content.

I rather the content to be shown in a `input` area I provided after I click a button.
I'm not sure if I should use input field or textarea field after a button is clicked.
Below is my code for the `input` field I wish my content to be shown after retrieving it:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <input name="" id="retrieveText" placeholder="Sample Text" value="" type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for re-editing the title for me.  I'm really bad at clarifying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('retrieveText').value=evt.target.result;
```

Comment: ah >.<" omg what was I been thinking...thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks!!